# google bigquery selecting rows with multiple values in repeating field

Tags: google-bigquery

Lets say I have a schema: 
key STRING  NULLABLE
values  INTEGER REPEATED

Now, please note that second column is a repeated field of integers,

Lets say the data is something like:

key:'abc' 
values: 1 2 3    (3 separate values, same for below values)

key:'def' 
values: 1 2 5

key:'ghi'
values: 1 6 9

And here I wish to find out keys which has values 1 and 2 ? Expecting 'abc' and 'def' as result set.

Looking for a query for this. I want an 'and' ('in' does not work here). I need those both values to be present for any key to return as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  key,
  SUM(values = 1 or values = 2) WITHIN RECORD AS check
FROM yourtable 
HAVING check = 2
```

Comment: so far this is the most clean answer considering google bq does not have anything cleaner than this like 'select key from [x] where values containsAll(...)'. But when doing programatic things, when u have too many values to choose from, above approach does not help much as query needs to be constantly changed and can not predict the time performance every time especially when application is client facing. But this is definitely most clean answer from all other alternatives out there with self joins and group bys. good answer!

Comment: @ppa - your question here was very specific - there was no single sign in it that you wanted more generic solution (as it sounds in your comment). If you can post another question with more generic ask - i hope we can find even better fit solution

Comment: yup agree, your solution is correct for the question asked given there is no better solution in bq for this. thanks again.